# Como hago para que el mapa de Mapbox muestre la ubicación de 1 solo registro? En Power BI

Tags: powerbi, mapbox

Lo que sucede es que tengo una base de datos con muchas direcciones y sus coordenadas, y cada una de estas direcciones están asociadas a la ciudad que corresponde, cuando filtro por ciudad en Power BI, el mapa funciona correctamente siempre y cuando haya más de un registro en la ciudad, si únicamente hay 1 registro, es decir una sola dirección asociada a una ciudad, entonces el mapa tira error al querer filtrar por esta ciudad que solo tiene asociada una dirección. El error que aparece es el siguiente: "input/output "interpolate" expressions must be arranged with input values in strictly ascending order".

Gracias

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.